# HTML string replace tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML string which contains various elements.
Consider following is the HTML string -

```
var contentHTML = '<p>Some random string</p><p><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><span some style></span></p><p><span style="font-size: 16.8px;"><b>Ingredients</b></span></p><p>Again some string</p><p><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>';
```

My requirement is to get tag before and after each `img` tag. If tag before `img` tag is `p` tag, then replace it with `<figure>` and closing `</p>` with `</figure>`.

I tried looping through `img` tag and able to get image details perfectly.

How can replace elements before and after image.

```
$(this.content).find('img').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prev());
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

String I require -

```
var contentHTML = '<p>Some random string</p><figure><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><span some style></span></figure><p><span style="font-size: 16.8px;"><b>Ingredients</b></span></p><p>Again some string</p><figure><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></figure>';
```

Comment: you input contentHTML doesn't match with your requirement

Comment: I think the `<p>` and `</p>` are meant that surround the `<img>`, although I agree that the wording is a but ambiguous. Also I wonder what happened to the `<span some style></span>` that directly follows the `<img>` in the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `replaceWith` (*comments inline*)

```
var $contentHTML = $( "<div>" + contentHTML + "</div>");

$contentHTML.find( "img" ).each( function(){ //iterate all img elements
  var $parentP = $(this).parent(); //get the parent element
  if ( $parentP[0].nodeName == "P" ) //check if the parent Element is P
  {
     var innerHTML = $parentP.html(); //save the innerHTML value
     $parentP.replaceWith( "<figure>" + innerHTML + "</figure>" ); //replace with figure and retain saved html value
  }
});
console.log($contentHTML.html());
```

**Demo**

```js
var contentHTML = `<p>Some random string</p><p><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><span some style></span></p><p><span style="font-size: 16.8px;"><b>Ingredients</b></span></p><p>Again some string</p><p><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>`;

var $contentHTML = $( "<div>" + contentHTML + "</div>");

$contentHTML.find( "img" ).each( function(){
  var $parentP = $(this).parent();
  if ( $parentP[0].nodeName == "P" )
  {
     var innerHTML = $parentP.html();
     $parentP.replaceWith( "<figure>" + innerHTML + "</figure>" );
  }
});
console.log($contentHTML.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `replace` and `regular expression`:

```js
var contentHTML = '<p>Some random string</p><p><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"><span some style></span></p><p><span style="font-size: 16.8px;"><b>Ingredients</b></span></p><p>Again some string</p><p><img src="xyz.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></p>';
var result=contentHTML.replace(/<p([^>]*?)>\s*?<img([\s\S]*?)<\/p>/g,'<figure$1><img$2</figure>');
console.log(result);
```